# Display issues after failed attempt to install amdgpu drivers on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, amdgpu, 21.04

My system is a ThinkPad T14 (Gen. 1) with AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 4750u (which has an integrated Renoir GPU). OS is Ubuntu 21.04 with Kernel 5.11.

It was working properly until yesterday when, out of nowhere, it did not want to re-boot nor shutdown. There was no reaction to `sudo shutdown -h now` nor `sudo reboot` nor when I used the commands from the GUI. So I forcefully powered it down by holding the power button.

After I had rebooted it, it did not recognize the external monitor (HDMI) anymore. Also the brightness adjust for the built-in monitor didn't work anymore (the keyboard shortcut works, I can see the slider moving in the menu, but the display doesn't change the brightness).

The output of `$ xrandr` doesn't list the hdmi port. It only lists the built-in `Screen 0`.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Several reboots and attempts to fix broken packages didn't change anything.

What could have caused this? Some days ago I tried to install amdgpu drivers but it failed and caused the computer to not boot properly. So I rolled back the whole install (amdgpu comes with an uninstall-script). I later learned that amdgpu drivers don't work with Kernel 5.11. After the rollback, everything worked fine again, so I'm not really sure if this is just a coincidence or the cause of the issues.

Right now, `glxgears -info` tells me that it is using llvmpipe drivers, which afaik means that the GPU isn't being used at all.

```
$ glxgears -info
GL_RENDERER   = llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits)
GL_VERSION    = 3.1 Mesa 21.0.1
GL_VENDOR     = Mesa/X.org
```

Some suspicious lines in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[   292.244] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c4
[   292.246] (--) PCI:*(7@0:0:0) 1002:1636:17aa:5081 rev 209, Mem @ 0xc60000000/268435456, 0xc70000000/2097152, 0xfd300000/524288, I/O @ 0x00001000/256
[   292.247] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   292.247] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   292.247] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.247]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   292.247]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   292.247] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[   292.247] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   292.247] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   292.247] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   292.247] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   292.247] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   292.247] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   292.248] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.248]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 19.1.0
[   292.248]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   292.248]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.311] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[   292.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[   292.312] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.312]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 19.1.0
[   292.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   292.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.312] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   292.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   292.312] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.312]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.20.11
[   292.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   292.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.312] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   292.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   292.312] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.312]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 0.5.0
[   292.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   292.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.312] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   292.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   292.312] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.312]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 2.5.0
[   292.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   292.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.312] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon chipsets:
        [long list of ATI/AMD graphics cards]
[   292.317] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   292.317] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   292.317] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   292.317] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   292.317] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   292.317] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   292.317] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   292.317] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   292.317] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   292.317] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   292.317]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 0.0.2
[   292.317]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   292.317] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 7@0:0:0
[   292.317] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[   292.317] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   292.317] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   292.317] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32

[   292.407] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[   292.408] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   292.408] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   292.408] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[   292.408] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   292.408] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   292.408] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[   292.408] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.

[...]
```

**Does anyone know what's going on here and can please help me to fix it?**

From what I found out so far, my best bet to actually make use of the GPU would be to re-install the system with Ubuntu 20.04. But I would also be happy to just have the current system back to normal, even if it isn't making use of the GPU..

Any help very much appreciated! Cheers, Fred

Comment: Oh boy, the more I dig into this, the more I think that taking the AMD option was a bad choice at this point in time. What people say is basically: Use the latest kernel because the performance is way better for AMD processors but use the 5.4 LTS kernel because GPU drivers won't work with later versions. What should I do now? And it looks like AMD doesn't care more for Linux than Nvidia did before (I had too many issues with Nvidia Optimus drivers on my T420 and I thought it would be better with AMD).

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you installed the AMD pro driver in the first place? The drivers built into the kernel seem to work fine.

Comment: Because the graphics performance was meh and I was under the impression that I needed to install AMD drivers manually to get the full performance. My bad, that I chose the pro version :-P Now I know better. But how do I roll back to the state before I made this failed experiment?

Comment: So I ended up re-installing the machine with 20.04 this time. It is now running with out-of-the-box Renoir drives and everything works fine. Although running `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` yielded tons of `W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/*.bin for module amdgpu` errors. Should I be concerned about this? I can remember that I had this with a fresh install of 21.04 as well...